# Create an Insert form in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, forms, insert

I'm trying to create an Insert form in laravel to add new information on a MySQL database, but I don't know how to do it. I have this code, but I don´t know hot to code it in laravel

```
$vide= $_POST['idelic'];
  $vnom= $_POST['nomemp'];
  $vequ= $_POST['equlic'];
  $vnoms= $_POST['nomsof'];
  $vord= $_POST['ordcom'];
  $videp= $_POST['idemp'];

  $insert= "insert into lic values ('$vide', '$vnom', '$vequ', '$vnoms', '$vord', '$videp')";
  $result= mysqli_query($conect, $insert);

  if ($result) {
     echo "<script>
            alert('Insertado exitosamente');
            window.location= 'Insertar_Licencia.php'
</script>";
```

Could anybody help me?
 Thank you in anvance.

Comment: You can learn basic crud here. https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-crud-application-tutorialexample.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we must start from the beginning. First, you'll need a License model.

Use this artisan command to generate the **Model**, the **Controller** and the **Migration**.

```
php artisan make:model License -mc
```

Please read about how to access the request data [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#accessing-the-request)

A really **simplified** example would be:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $lic = new License;
    $lic->vnom = $request->input('nomemp');
    $lic->vequ = $request->input('equlic');
    $lic->vnoms= $request->input('nomsof');
    $lic->vord = $request->input('ordcom');
    $lic->videp= $request->input('idemp');
    $lic->save();

}
```